# What is the worst approximation error occurring using Java float to represent amounts of money?

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal, primitive-types

I'm managing a piece of legacy code that uses `float` variables to manages amount of money and this cause some approximation issue.

I know that this is not the correct way to represent money and that should be used the `BigDecimal` type but the refactoring of all the legacy code requires a lot of time and meanwhile I would like to understand what is the worst error introduced by this approximation?

Also a link point to some theoretical document that explain in a detailed (but understandable) manner the problem (and how to estimate the worst case error)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say. The errors compound, so it very much depends upon the calculation you do and how many times you do it.

Comment: The extent of the error is probably proportional to (i) the number of operations on each float (the more arithmetic you do the larger the potential error) and (ii) the amounts (the larger the amounts, the larger the errors)

Comment: As an example of (ii) above, 1,000,000,095 (1 billion and change) as a float is 1,000,000,064, or an error of more than 30 units of currency (say dollars).

Comment: The *least* approximation error is one cent , which is already too much.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but what I would like to know is something more theoretical. For example I know that the java float has a mantissa of 7 digit. Can I assume that ALL the values that requires 7 or less digit are perfectly represented? Furthermore can I assume that the error is always smaller than an unit of the 7th most significant digit?

Comment: No, even with a few digits (like 3) representation won't be accurate anymore. Play a bit with http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/ to see it for yourself